# Switch Case PDO não exibe

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Alterado mais dentro do titulo ainda, o caso funciona porem nao exibe o resultado.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT tipo FROM publicidade WHERE posicao='Lateral' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$exibe = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($exibe as $u) {
$tipo = $u->tipo;  // <-- corrigido baseado nos comentarios
switch ($tipo) {
case 'imagem':
echo "<img src='img/publicidade/$u->idpublicidade/$u->imagem' heigth='150' width='100%'>";
break;
case 'flash':
echo "<embed src='img/publicidade/$u->idpublicidade/$u->flash' width='720' height='90'></embed>";
break;
case 'codigo':
echo "$u->codigo";
break;
}}
```

alterado

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54598/discussion-on-question-by-arsom-nolasco-switch-case-pdo-nao-exibe)

Answer (score 2):

`FetchAll` faz o que diz: ele busca todos os resultados para uma consulta. Desde que a busca monte resultados, você obterá uma matriz indexada.

Você deve mudar todas as consultas para instruções preparadas e substituir o seguinte:

- `$stmt->fetchAll();` por `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
- ou então `$tipo = $u['tipo'];` por `$tipo = $u->tipo;`